# Google Map inside modal not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I have a modal where when it is clicked the map show up, but the map is not working but instead a gray image is shown.

```
  <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="resize()">Show Modal</button>
    <!--MODAL-->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Warning!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">

                    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
                    <div id="map" style="width: 580px; height:400px"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my srcipt is from google auto complete places, when the map is not inside the modal, it is working perfectly fine.

```
  <script>
            // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
            // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
            // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

            // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
            // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
            // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
var map;

            function initAutocomplete() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
                    zoom: 13,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });

                // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
                var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
                var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
                map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

                // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
                map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
                    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
                });

                var markers = [];
                // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
                // more details for that place.
                searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
                    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

                    if (places.length == 0) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Clear out the old markers.
                    markers.forEach(function (marker) {
                        marker.setMap(null);
                    });
                    markers = [];

                    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                    places.forEach(function (place) {
                        var icon = {
                            url: place.icon,
                            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                        };

                        // Create a marker for each place.
                        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: icon,
                            title: place.name,
                            position: place.geometry.location
                        }));

                        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                            // Only geocodes have viewport.
                            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                        } else {
                            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                        }
                    });
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                });

            }

function resize(){

            $('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            });
}

        </script>
```

[image]

I tried doing this [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037272/google-map-not-showing-on-bootstrap-modal) but it is giving me

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```js
      // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
            // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
            // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

            // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
            // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
            // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
            var map;

            function initAutocomplete() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
                    zoom: 13,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });

                // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
                var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
                var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
                map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

                // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
                map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
                    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
                });

                var markers = [];
                // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
                // more details for that place.
                searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
                    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

                    if (places.length == 0) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Clear out the old markers.
                    markers.forEach(function (marker) {
                        marker.setMap(null);
                    });
                    markers = [];

                    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                    places.forEach(function (place) {
                        var icon = {
                            url: place.icon,
                            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                        };

                        // Create a marker for each place.
                        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: icon,
                            title: place.name,
                            position: place.geometry.location
                        }));

                        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                            // Only geocodes have viewport.
                            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                        } else {
                            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                        }
                    });
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                });

            }




$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                });
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      <body>
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/>Show Modal</button>
        <!--MODAL-->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Warning!</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">

                        <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
                        <div id="map" style="width: 580px; height:400px"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyADR3ipXgTLZd7uIcl3NBUujxF3kKp9rFk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
            
            </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error you receive states that `jQuery` is not included properly in your project.

Comment: for my codes there is no error, but when i tried adding the "answer" in the linked question, thats when the errors comes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var map;

function initAutocomplete() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // ....
}
$(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    });
});
```

You have wrapped

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

inside `function resize() {}` that is never executed. Try wrapping it with `jQuery`'s `$(document).ready(function(){});` instead.

Comment: there is a new error. when i place the jquery imports before the google api imports it will not work, if it is after the google api... it is working but there will be an Uncaught ReferenceError..

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle with your code? It's the only way someone can help you debug your code

Comment: i already solve the error.. i dont really know how to paste the file in snipset, since i have a lot of imports... but currently the dropdown search is not showing but if i tried to press the arrow key down it still works

Answer (score 0):

This kind fo error ($ is not defined) means that you have not initialized a javascript library in your code.

and as you are using:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        });
```

you need to add jquery at the top of your script. Something like this:

You may find information here: [w3schools jquery init](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)

Start by solving the js error and possibly the map will load.

Comment: no for the current code there is no error, but if i tried the answer in the linked question.. it returns that error.

Comment: The problem is that a map cannot be shown if initialized into a component that has display:none during map init time. So, into the on('shown') function you need to call the init() function of the google map.