# Embedded Google Map in modal is showing blank until window resizes manually

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, typescript

I have a google map that is embedded into a modal, but when clicking to open the modal, the map appears blank.

[image]

After googling i thought i found a solution using jquery to resize the window again but it doesnt seem to work.

The current code i'm using:

component.html:

```
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    <a href="#" onclick="$('#map-modal').modal('open');">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="./assets/1.jpg" class="z-depth-4">
          <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Map's and Directions</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

    <div id="map">
      <script type="text/javascript">
          google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
      </script>
    </div>
```

component.css

```
#map {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

component.ts

```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  modalActions = new EventEmitter<string|MaterializeAction>();

  ngOnInit() {
    var mapProp = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function(){
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        });
    });
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY"></script>
```

Can anyone see what im missing?

I m doing the app in angular 2 btw

Comment: i am not that much of an angular guy but you should initialize the map on the modal `init` if you are using bootstrap modal try initializing the google maps init code inside the `show.bs.modal` event rather than `document.ready()` there is a known issue with the google maps if initialized inside parent having `display:none`

Comment: Hi, im using materialcss. but if i move the maps init code into `openModal( { this.modalActions.emit({action:"modal",params:['open']}); }` the map doesnt show at all

Comment: no you donot have to move the map inside the `openModal` function but rather bind the event for modal , see here if that helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037272/google-map-not-showing-on-bootstrap-modal

Comment: I dont quite understand how to translate that across. Ive updated my app component in the question and added the html for the card that opens the modal